# How to pass a dynamic Javascript variable in a Href tag as a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with 6 identical links used to track referrals from site A to B using the following link structure:

```
<a href="https://example.com/program?referralToken=123456789">Get Started</a>
```

I'm looking to use a simple Javascript, without dependencies on any external CDN library, where I can pass the dynamic **referralToken** **value** through the href tag. Something similar to this:

```
<script>
    var referralTokenValue = 123456789;
</script>

<a href="https://example.com/program?referralToken=+'referralTokenValue'">Get Started</a>
```

**Limitations**:

1. Href ID's can't be used as there're 6 identical CTAs;
2. Only the referralToken value is dynamic;

How can I get to use the **referralTokenValue** as a variable inside the href tag?

Comment: Are the links already on the page and you just want to append the token to each `href`? It might help to see a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the specific problem you're having.

Comment: The links are already embed in the page, with the "https://example.com/program?referralToken=" being fixed, and the "referralTokenValue" being appended to the URL link where the expected rendered version would yield: https://example.com/program?referralToken=123456789

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what **"dynamic"** means in your question. but

Try this:

```html
<script>
    var referralTokenValue = 123456789;
</script>

<a href=`https://example.com/program?referralToken=${referralTokenValue}`>Get Started</a>
```

Is that your solution?
Also check sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-microservice-x08s8

Comment: By dynamic, I meant that it will be changes constantly, however, the sandbox solution and my local test did not yielded the desired outcome as the ${referralTokenValue} does not get replaced with the value (123456789) in both rendered versions.  I ended up getting the URL link "https://example.com/program?referralToken=${referralTokenValue}" and not the https://example.com/program?referralToken=123456789.